# Need advice for dynamically changing linux conf/yaml files via API or tool like Consul

Tags: consul, etcd

I am looking for tools/software for dynamically changing Linux conf/YAML files via API or tool like Consul.

If you have any experience on consul, please give feedback about creating templates for conf/YAML files, and without using service can it be done via consul?

Answer (score 0):

[Consul Template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template) or [Gomplate](https://github.com/hairyhenderson/gomplate) can be used to template configuration files based on changes in a backend data source.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/consul-template provides a basic example of a template which regenerates file contents when keys are added to Consul's key-value store.